# calculate average of second set

Tags: arithmetic

let us consider following problem:

Set $S$ and Set $T$ both contain x elements. The average of Set S is $40$. If the average of Set $S$ and Set $T$ combined is $50$, which of the following must be true?

I. The average of Set T is 60.

II. The range of Set T is greater than that of Set S.

III. x is an even number

(A)  I only

(B)  I & II

(C)  II only

(D) I & III

(E)  All of the above

answer of this  questions says that,average of Set $T$  is $60$,i could not understand,when it says that set $S$ and $T$ contains both $x$ elements,does each one contain $x$ or total?if total let say that $s$ contain $2$ member,then sum of all number of set $s$ is $80$,if total average of $5$ member(let say  $x=5$) is $50$,then total sum is $50*5=250$,which means that total sum of set $T$ is $250-80=170$,then average is $170/3= 56.666666666666666666666666666667$,why it should be $60$?please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes option 1 . It means each one contains x .

average = total strength / number of elements

total is set S = $ 40 *x $

total in set S and T  = $ 50*2*x $  . (because total elements in set S and T together is $2x$

so total in set T = total in set S and T - total is set S 
= $ 60 * x $

so average is 60 in set T containing x elements

Comment: that is what i wanted,so it  means that both contain each $x$ element,is it correct  ordering of question?is it not better to say that each contain $x$?it is mathematical problem,not english :(

Comment: Ya it is given "both" so it means each contain x elements

Comment: i was thinking that together they contain $x$ element

Comment: if it is given "both together contain " then this would mean what you are saying . "both contain" here means each contain.

Comment: thanks very much for your help

Comment: No problem . Happy learning .:)